# How to update every object element in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query

My structure is something like this:

```
{
 "_id": "13hu13o13uuo1",
 "profiles": {
  "1": [1,2,3],
  "847891": [3, 4],
  ..
 }
}
```

"profiles" is an "object-array"/dictionary that has dynamic keys and their values are arrays.

How can I update all profile elements, inserting, let's say, 11 in every array?

Version: Mongo 4.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the syntax for the other answer is technically correct, I recommend not using the aggregation pipeline `$merge` approach for most usecases. The main reason is that such a pipeline is not atomic.

You can simply execute the exact same logic using the [aggregation pipeline update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) feature, hence gaining the atomic property of the update operations in Mongo.

Here's how this looks:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "profiles": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$profiles"
            },
            "as": "element",
            "in": {
              k: "$$element.k",
              v: {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$element.v",
                  [
                    11
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QiUI1neF8Ry)

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I didn't know about this new feature, so I solved using forEach + save loop, but it took about 11s for 100 documents and your solution only took 0.3s :)